# How to use map method in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Output is not showing in the browser while using map method but it is showing while calling elements one by one from array. Answer please

```
const App = () => {
  const items = [
    {
      title:"University Expenses",
      amount:267
    },
    {
      title:"Car Insurance",
      amount:1200
    },
    {
      title:"Bike Expenses",
      amount:5000
    }
  ]
  return(
    <>
  {items.map(( val , i )=>{
      <ExpenseItem key={i} title = {val.title} amount = {val.amount}/>
  })}
  </>
  )
}
```

Code of ExpenseItem component

```
import React from "react";

const ExpenseItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="expense_div">
         <h2>{props.title}</h2> 
        <div>
          <button>${props.amount}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
};

export default ExpenseItem
```

Comment: additional hint: try to avoid using the index as a key in jsx if possible. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not return anything in the `map`'s callback function, the components rendered a list of `undefined`. The solution is to `return` appropriated values in the `map` callback function (here is the `ExpenseItem` component)

```
return (
    <>
  {items.map(( val , i )=>{
      return <ExpenseItem key={i} title = {val.title} amount = {val.amount}/>
  })}
  </>
)
```

or shorthand, notice the `()` bracket

```
return (
    <>
  {items.map(( val , i )=>(
      <ExpenseItem key={i} title = {val.title} amount = {val.amount}/>
  ))}
  </>
)
```

#### References

[Array `map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

You're very close, the issue is here:

```
  {items.map(( val , i )=>{
      <ExpenseItem key={i} title = {val.title} amount = {val.amount}/>
  })}
```

In an arrow function, when you put brackets after the arrow that means you're wanting to execute multiple lines of code, and need an explicit return. If you use parentheses instead, it's an expression that returns automatically. See [here](https://medium.com/@cyn7117/using-curly-brackets-and-parentheses-with-arrow-functions-e0b13c9f311b)

So what you want is either

```
  {items.map(( val , i )=>(
      <ExpenseItem key={i} title = {val.title} amount = {val.amount}/>
 ))}
```

Or

```
  {items.map(( val , i )=>{
      return <ExpenseItem key={i} title = {val.title} amount = {val.amount}/>
  })}
```